# Remove the swapped duplicates from dictinonary k

Tags: python

I have a dictionary containing following keys

dict_keys(['0:2', '0:3', '0:8', '0:9', '1:5', '1:6', '1:8', '1:9', '2:0', '3:0', '4:9', '5:1', '6:1', '7:8', '8:0', '8:1', '8:7', '9:0', '9:1', '9:4'])

I want to remove the swapped duplicates. For example: 0:2 and 2:0 is same and I want to keep one of them.

Final output should be

dict_keys(['0:2', '0:3', '0:8', '0:9', '1:5', '1:6', '1:8', '1:9', '4:9', '7:8'])
How can I do it ?

Comment: Can you provide the dictionary

Comment: What would the desired output list look like if the original list was lst = ['0:2', '2:0', '2:0']

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
lst = ['0:2', '0:3', '0:8', '0:9', '1:5', '1:6', '1:8', '1:9', '2:0', '3:0', '4:9', '5:1', '6:1', '7:8', '8:0', '8:1', '8:7', '9:0', '9:1', '9:4']

for a in lst:
    lst.remove(a[::-1]) # here `a[::-1]` for reversing the string.
print(lst)
```

### OR

```py
lst = ['0:2', '0:3', '0:8', '0:9', '1:5', '1:6', '1:8', '1:9', '2:0', '3:0', '4:9', '5:1', '6:1', '7:8', '8:0', '8:1', '8:7', '9:0', '9:1', '9:4']

[lst.remove(a[::-1]) for a in lst] # here `a[::-1]` for reversing the string.
print(lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
['0:2', '0:3', '0:8', '0:9', '1:5', '1:6', '1:8', '1:9', '4:9', '7:8']
```

Comment: it can even fit in one line with `[lst.remove(a[::-1]) for a in lst]`

Comment: @MariusROBERT I know.